# Center table on landscape page

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment, landscape

I have a rather wide table for which I have a designated page in landscape mode. The rest of the document is in portrait mode. Currently, the first row of the table begins at the very top of the page and ends somewhere in the middle. I'd like the table to be vertically centered though. How can I achieve this? I'm using the `tabular` environment.

Comment: `\begin{center} \end{center}` don't work?

Comment: `\centering` should have the same effect right? If not, I could try. I solved the problem by adding the `table` environment (see answer).

Comment: Yes. `\centering` has the same effect but it must be putted on an environment. If you don't want the a floating table (`\begin{table}`) you can use the `center` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it. Initially, I only had

```
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*12c}
% Content goes here
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

I had to place the table in a `table` environment, i.e.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*12c}
% Content goes here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: You might want to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment inside a `table`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that. I'll change my answer.

Comment: you may also want to consider changing `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}` to `\begin{tabular}{|*12{c|}}` or better `\begin{tabular}{*12c}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the package [TABLE](http://river-valley.com/table/) from [River Valley](http://river-valley.com/). The package provides the following:

> - include a landscape table as a float.
> - format the caption exactly to the width of the table.
> - some other hooks that would add a little extra vertical space around horizontal rules in the tabular.

And it automatically centre the table on the page.

Here is a modified example from the readme-file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts,array}
\usepackage{Table}

\begin{document}

\TABLE{\label{tab407}Distribution of Turnover and Market
Capitalisation of Top `50' Companies listed at NSE}
{\tabcolsep8pt\extrarowheight2pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrcrrrrrr@{}}
\br
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Turnover}\\\ns
 & \crule{13} \\
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Amount (Rs. crore)} & &\multicolumn{6}{c}{\% to total}\\
 & \crule{6} & & \crule{6}\\
Companies& 1995--96 & 1996--97  & 1997--98  & 1998--99 & 1999--00&  2000--01&&
1995--96    &1996--97   &1997--98   &1998--99   &1999--00   &2000--01       \\
\mr
Manufacturing               &49,909 &131,109&   132,678 &   88,224  &   139,742& 124,779 && 79.29&  45.88   &37.43 & 23.13 & 18.78 & 9.85\\
Financial Services  &10,859 &100,037&   54,071  &   26,500  &   34,308&  17,559 &   &   17.25&  35.01   &15.25 & 6.95    & 4.61  & 1.39\\
F.M.C.G                         &704        &43,818 &   155,148 &   94,240  &   38,011&  32,438 &   &   1.12 & 15.33    &43.77 & 24.71 & 5.11    & 2.56\\
I.T.                                &0          &159        &   2,579       &   138,148 &   369,315& 957,159&   &   0.00 & 0.06     &0.73    & 36.22 & 49.63 & 75.56\\
Pharmaceuticals         &158        &408        &   1,976       &   9,029       &   48,230&  21,085 &   &   0.25 & 0.14     &0.56    & 2.37  & 6.48  & 1.66\\
Others                          &1,313  &10,229 &   8,048       &   25,285  &   114,481& 113,803 && 2.09 & 3.58     &2.27    & 6.63  & 15.39 & 8.98\\
\mr
Total                             &62,943   &285,762&   354,500&    381,427&    744,088 & 1,266,823 &   &   100.00  & 100.00 &  100.00  & 100.00    & 100.00    & 100.00\\
\br                                                                                 
& \\
& \\
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Market Capitalisation}\\
 & \crule{13}\\
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Amount (Rs. crore)} & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\% to total}\\\ns
 & \crule{6} & & \crule{6}\\
Companies   & 1995--96  & 1996--97  & 1997--98  & 1998--99  & 1999--00 & 2000--01   &   & 1995--96 &  1996--97  & 1997--98  & 1998--99  & 1999--00 & 2000--01\\
\br  
Manufacturing               &139,546&162,188&177,371&   106,572&    151,692 &96,718& &  62.05   &62.18  &54.95  &34.39  &20.53  &20.79\\
Financial Services  &25,655 &29,083 &34,061 &   18,334& 36,209  &36,460&     & 11.41    &11.15  &10.55  &5.92   &4.90   &7.84\\
F.M.C.G                         &22,648 &29,888 &59,199 &   90,773& 79,522  &80,497&     & 10.07    &11.46  &18.34  &29.29  &10.76  &17.30\\
I.T.                                &0          &0          &8,434  &   45,742& 306,418 &106,095&    & 0.00     &0.00   &2.61   &14.76  &41.48  &22.80\\
Pharmaceuticals         &4,168  &4,728  &8,176  &   24,221& 19,324  &21,035&     & 1.85     &1.81   &2.53   &7.82   &2.62   &4.52\\
Others                          &32,880 &34,934 &35,545 &   24,272& 145,609 &124,502&    & 14.62    &13.39  &11.01  &7.83   &19.71  &26.76\\
Total                               &224,897&260,821&322,786&   309,912&    738,774 &465,306&& 100.00   & 100.00&   100.00      &100.00     &100.00 &100.00 \\
\br
\end{tabular}}
{\textsc{f.m.c.g.} Fast Moving Consumer Goods Market
Concentration in Emerging Asian Markets: end 2000 Market
Concentration in Emerging Asian Markets: end 2000\\
 \textsc{i.t.}  Information Technology}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]